# Style HTML of a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I am programmatically setting the content of a `WebView`.  I'd like to add some styling around the content, such as padding and font-size, but, with what I have, the styles aren't recognized:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView)browserView.findViewById(R.id.webview);

String content = GetContent();

StringBuilder sbContent = new StringBuilder();
sbContent.append("<!doctype html>");
sbContent.append("<body style=\"padding:10em;font-size:12em;\">");
sbContent.append(content);
sbContent.append("</body>");
sbContent.append("</html>");

mWebView.loadData(content.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try using valid HTML. For example, you have `</html>` with no `<html>`.

Second, the content in question may override your styling. You would need to look at the combined result to see whether or not this will work.

Comment: The first `append` of the `StringBuilder` is where I'm declaring the opening `<html>`: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp  The content is really basic HTML, with some `img` tags and paragraph breaks, nothing that should override the styles.

Comment: @KrisB: "The first append of the StringBuilder is where I'm declaring the opening <html>" -- no, it is not. Please click on the link you provided in your comment and read that page. Note how in their sample, they have an `<html>` tag *after* the `<!DOCTYPE html>`.